# What if there is an interruption in the geth sync process

Tags: go-ethereum, linux, geth-debugging, debian

I run `geth attach` command that s currently doing some sync with the blockchain.  I can see the status in the `geth` JavaScript console like,

When I execute the command of `eth.syncing`, 
The output is,

```
{
  currentBlock: 4050305,
  highestBlock: 4764190,
  knownStates: 5436672,
  pulledStates: 5431426,
  startingBlock: 1694745
}
```

I can see the remaining blocks with executing the command, `eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock`

The output is `713055`

Let's imagine, at this point, the internet connection or the electricity goes away. Will the blockchain synchronization start from the current point or from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronization should be able to resume from the current point. You shouldn't need to start from the beginning unless some file corruption happened due to something like a sudden shutdown of the disk.  Losing network connection is very unlikely to cause any file corruption.

Comment: This is really good to know as I still have about `500000+` blocks to go

Comment: Hello, after finishing the downloading and sync, how often I need to go through the procedure or this is one-time work?

Comment: Your client will stay in sync as long as it is running; when there is a network protocol upgrade (a hard fork), then you need to upgrade your client.  So far I think those only happen 1-2 times a year.